# Python - Reshape numpy array to different grid

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am looking for a solution to a problem I have, unfortunately searching the internet provided no answer. I have an array of data (20 x 100 points) with rectangular pixels, pixels in the x-direction have of size of 2 m and pixels in y-direction are 10 m. The total area of my array is 200 m x 200 m and the axes range from -100m to +100 m.

I want to reshape/reproject this data to a regular sized grid of (101 x 101 points) where the size of a pixel in x and y direction is 1 m. Points within the new array should be filled with the corresponding value of the old array

I have added a small piece of code to serve as an example below.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.arange(0,100,1)
arr = np.tile(x, (20,1))
x_size = 2
y_size = 10
plt.imshow(arr, aspect = 'auto', extent = [-100,100,-100, 100])
```

Comment: have you tried to use a [min max scaler](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html) approach  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it with `scipy.ndimage.zoom()`, you just need to calculate the proper scaling factor.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import scipy.ndimage

import scipy.ndimage

# generate dummy input
arr = np.arange(20 * 100).reshape((20, 100))

# resize
resized = sp.ndimage.zoom(arr, [101 / 20, 101 / 100])
print(resized.shape)
# prints: (101, 101) as expected

plt.imshow(resized)
plt.show()
```

Comment: note that you may want to try out different interpolations other than the default, by playing around with the "order" argument.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!